# Dumping tables and schemas that are accessible to me only?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Is it possible to dump tables and schemas that are accessible to me only in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "only" modifies in your question. Do you mean you want to query by permissions and find the tables to which only one user has access?

Comment: Hi Devin, yes that is correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First find the relations you have access to (this can be tweaked to pull schemas too)

```
 with relnames as (SELECT relname FROM pg_class
      WHERE relkind='r' and relnamespace = (select oid from pg_namespace where nspname = 'public'))
select array_agg(relname) from relnames WHERE has_table_privilege(SESSION_USER, relname, 'SELECT');
```

Now we aren't quite done now because that just creates an array of tables we have access to.  We now need to change this to use array_to_string to get something we can feed into pg_dump:

```
 with relnames as (SELECT relname FROM pg_class
      WHERE relkind='r' and relnamespace = (select oid from pg_namespace where nspname = 'public'))
select array_to_string(array_agg(relname), ' -t ') from relnames WHERE has_table_privilege(SESSION_USER, relname, 'SELECT');
```

the above queries can be tweaked (changing the pg_namespace subquery) to pull namespaces you have access to and you could change it to a join to pull fully qualified table names.